addEventListener not working for element selected by a new class added from javascript
I'm trying to make the button work when the ratings are clicked. Otherwise I don't won't the button addEventListener to work
I did check if all the elements are correctly looped through using console.log. I didn't find any mistakes in my code
Code


"use strict";

const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const activeBtn = document.querySelector(".btn--active");
const cardFront = document.querySelector(".card__side--front");
const cardBack = document.querySelector(".card__side--back");
const ratingNum = document.querySelectorAll(".card__rating-num");

ratingNum.forEach((rating) => {
  rating.addEventListener("click", () => {
    btn.classList.add("btn--active");
  });
});

activeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  cardFront.style.transform = "rotateY(-180deg)";
  cardBack.style.transform = "rotateY(0)";
});
<div class="card__footer">
  <div class="card__rating u-mbm">
    <span class="card__rating-num">1</span>
    <span class="card__rating-num">2</span>
    <span class="card__rating-num">3</span>
    <span class="card__rating-num">4</span>
    <span class="card__rating-num">5</span>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Submit</a>
</div>




Where did you include your console.log()? Does your script run before the DOM is loaded?

I added console.log() inside the loop, Script runs after the DOM is loaded

@mykaf Why would that matter? If they run it before the DOM is loaded, the list will be empty and the loop won't iterate at all.

Are you sure the error is coming from this code? I converted it to an executable snippet and there's no error.

@Barmar It's because of the next block of code I think. I have now edited the code snippet

@mykaf please refer to the updated code snippet, as the error is caused by the next block of code

There's no element with class="btn--active" in the HTML. What do you expect activeBtn to be?

That class is only added when you click on one of the numbers. But you're trying to add the event listener before the class is added.

@Barmar The question is now updated... What do you suggest I do.

You're trying to get activeBtn before the button has been made active by clicking on one of the rating numbers. Since there's no active button yet, activeBtn is null and you can't add an event listener to it.
Instead, add the event listener to btn, and it can check whether it's active.


"use strict";

const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const activeBtn = document.querySelector(".btn--active");
const cardFront = document.querySelector(".card__side--front");
const cardBack = document.querySelector(".card__side--back");
const ratingNum = document.querySelectorAll(".card__rating-num");

ratingNum.forEach((rating) => {
  rating.addEventListener("click", () => {
    btn.classList.add("btn--active");
  });
});

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("btn--active")) {
    console.log("Clicked on submit");
  }
});
.btn {
  color: grey;
}

.btn.btn--active {
  color: black;
}
<div class="card__footer">
  <div class="card__rating u-mbm">
    <span class="card__rating-num">1</span>
    <span class="card__rating-num">2</span>
    <span class="card__rating-num">3</span>
    <span class="card__rating-num">4</span>
    <span class="card__rating-num">5</span>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Submit</a>
</div>




Hey, now that you have mentioned it, the solution seems obvious. It's been like a month since I started learning javaScript and I guess I didn't see it because,  I was tired from coding all day.  Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it!
